# IDE for working on Thunderbird extensions

Tags: software-development, web-development, email, ide, thunderbird

I'm maintaining a Mozilla Thunderbird extension. It's mostly a collection of Javascript, XUL, CSS and DTD files. I use git for revision control.

So far, I've been using a plain text editor with syntax highlighting, and a build script I've written myself, to work on the extension. I've been wondering - is there an IDE which would be appropriate to use for such a project?

Notes:

- Thunderbird and Firefox extensions are very similar, but - a TB extension is not a browser extension.
- In case it matters - this is a regular extension, not merely a "WebExtension". Or rather, it starts out as a WebExtension but uses a loophole to load itself as proper extension (with full access to TB's internal APIs). But if you have an answer that's "only" for WebExtensions, that helps too.